# Why the error using backward Euler is less than using Crank--Nicolson?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I'm reading the following paper

https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/ELECTRONIC_PAPERS/JMR06.CMAME.pdf

where calculates the solution of the time-dependent Navier--Stokes equations using different $\theta$-Schemes for the time, and finite element method in each time step (Taylor--Hood). My question is related with BWE (backward Euler) and CN (Crank--Nicolson). If we see the picture that I attach (Figure 2 of Section 4.1 of the paper) the error in the pressure using BWE is less than the error using CN, Is this possible? I understand that the CN method is better, so I would expect the pressure error to be lower using CN. I think it is ok, but I would like to know some explanation.

My second question is: BWE is order 1, and CN is order 2, but I see that in the pressure they have the same order. Why I can't see the order or the errors in these figures?

We can see the same behaviour in all the numerical tests, but I only attached one of them.

[image: Errors]

Comment: The fact that the relative performance is reversed between velocity and pressure suggests that there is some nontrivial dynamical effect in the discretized systems which is not negligible toward the left side of these graphs. In the case of BWE presumably it is the familiar improved stability of implicit methods in general. (That said I can't tell from context what "time step" actually means, which is problematic for a careful assessment...)

Comment: Thanks Ian, the time steps are $0.1\times 2^{-k}$, with $k=0,1,... 8$

Comment: They are using FEM for the spatial discretisation, but what finite elements exactly? P1-P1, P1-P1 bubble, P2-P1, other? If the error introduced by the space discretisation is not properly controlled, the estimation of the error introduced time discretisation becomes inconsistent.

Comment: Hi @PierreCarre, I implemented the same examples using Taylor--Hood with Pk-Pk-1. I tested with k=2,3,4, using Picard and Newton, obtaining the same results than in the paper. I tested with very refined meshes of triangles, and the paper uses squares.

Answer (score 1):

Typical error estimates for these algorithms are based on worst-case scenarios. However, on a specific problem, it's usually hard to predict which algorithm will perform the best.

As for CN behaving order 1 instead of order 2 -- my guess is that, if we check the list of assumptions in the theorem which guarantees order 2 for CN, one of them likely doesn't hold here.